# Storing lots of images on server compression

Tags: server, zip, compression, storage

We have a project which will generate lots (hundreds of thousands) of .PNG images that are around 1mb. Rapid serving is not a priority as we use the images internally, not front end.

We know to use filesystem not DB to store.

**We'd like to know how best to compress these images on the server to minimise long term storage costs.**

linux server

Answer (score 0):

They already are compressed, so you would need to recode the images into another lossless format, while preserving all of the information present in the PNG files. I don't know of a format that will do that, but you can roll your own by recoding the image data using a better lossless compressor (you can see [benchmarks here](http://imagecompression.info/gralic/)), and have a separate metadata file that retains the other information from the original .png files, so that you can reconstruct the original.

The best you could get losslessly, based on the benchmarks, would be about 2/3 of their current size. You would need to test the compressors on your actual data. Your mileage may vary.